# How to add Calendar Input to Botpress

Tags: calendar, botpress

So I'm creating a chatbot using Botpress.com and it's for restaurant reservations.

For the date and time I want the user to be able to click on the available dates, but sadly there is no such thing as calendar input. Is there a workaround that I could use?

Thanks in advance!